# How to rename splitfile[a-z] to splitfile[1-26]

Tags: rename, command, mv

I am trying to rename files named in the form of `splitfile[a-z]` to `splitfile[1-26].csv`, that is I want to rename `splitfilea` to `splitfile1.csv` and so on.
I tried the following command:

```
mv splitfile[a-z] splitfile[1-26].csv
```

but it doesn't work.Kindly help me, meanwhile I am trying with for loop.

Comment: You may want to consider padding with leading zeros, like `splitfile01.csv`.  The way you suggest, ordinary sorting will put them in the order `splitfile1`, `splitfile10`, `splitfile11`, ... `splitfile19`, `splitfile2`, `splitfile20`, ... which is often inconvenient.  In particular, doing `cat splitfile*.csv` will no longer combine them back into the proper order.

Answer (score 10):

With new `bash` you can use brace expansion of the form `{a..z}`:

```
i=1; for f in file{a..z}; do mv "$f.csv" "${f%?}$((i++)).csv"; done
```

Comment: `in file[a-z]` is work too but *unsorted*, so it can be tricked by `$(echo file[a-z] | sort)`

Comment: What about using `file*` instead of `file{a..z}`? I think it should work...

Comment: And please note that `do mv "$f.csv"` should be `do mv "$f"` according to the question.

Comment: @mohammad.k It cannot be `file*` because that would match `file_something_not_a_single_letter` too. Also it has to be `mv "$f.csv"` instead of `mv "$f"`, because `file{a..z}` matches `filea`, wiithout suffix `.csv`.

Comment: @jimmij I supposed that there are only files in the form `file{a..z}` in that directory. But you're answer is quite better. About `.csv`, it is not said in the question that files initially have the extension; so I still persist on my previous comment.

Comment: Was just about to post this! The only thing I would change is moving `((i++))` to its own line because I think that's cleaner. But that only matters if this is a script that's going to be reused.

Comment: @Costas - globs are sorted by locale by default.

Answer (score 7):

If you have the `perl` utility `rename` (sometimes called `prename`) you can use it to rename your files

```
rename -n 's/([a-z])$/ord($1)-96/e and $_ .= ".csv"' splitfile?
```

What this does is to take the last letter of your filenames matching `splitfile?`, convert the character to its ASCII ordinal equivalent (i.e. a=97, b=98, ...), subtract 96 and replace the matched letter with the result. For all filenames where this substitution was applied successfully the string ".csv" is appended.

The command above won't change your actual files (that's what the `-n` flag does), it will only print what it would do. Run it once, check the output and, if it is correct, run it again without the `-n`.

Answer (score 4):

With `zsh` one doesn't need to use a loop, just a `zmv` function:

```
autoload -U zmv
i=1 zmv -v '(file)[a-z].csv' '$1$((i++)).csv'
```

Or if not all the `file[a-z].csv` may exist:

```
letters=({a..z})
zmv -v '(file)([a-z]).csv' '$1$letters[(i)$2].csv'
```

Answer (score 1):

This `sh` script correctly renames files even if files are missing from the `a-z` sequence:

```
#!/bin/sh
for n in $(seq 26)
do
    f=$(printf $(printf 'file\%03o.csv' $((n+96))))
    [ -e $f ] && echo mv $f file$n.csv
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to do it with a POSIX shell, assuming all files exist in the `a-z` sequence:

```
#!/bin/sh
i=1
for f in file[a-z].csv
do
    echo mv $f file$i.csv
    i=$((i+1))
done
```

Comment: not exactly... consider the cases of matches on a and c but not b.

Comment: @mikeserv, yea, so far only the `perl` script seems to account for that.

Answer (score 0):

Another fairly portable solution...

```sh
    eval    set "'' $(dc -e'123[1-ddP32P97<a]salax')"  ### reverse-order lowercase ascii
    while   "${2+shift}" 2>&-                          ### only iterate while we should
    do      for f   in ./*["$1"].ext                   ### glob* is fine - sorting's done
            do      [ "${f%%*\]????}" ] &&             ### *null glob* kind of
            echo    mv "$f" "${f%?.*}${?%${10+?}}$#.${f##*.}"  ### echo doesn't mv much
    done;   done                                       ### $? zero-pads to two decimals
```

After doing the `set` line above, I then generated a test set for this solution like...

```sh
    eval '  for A   in  '"$(printf %1.s%s%1.s "$@" "" ";do for a in$@")"';
            do      echo  "$A$a" > "${A}file$a.ext";        done;   done'
```

That iteratively skips every two letters for every two letters... if that makes sense. The results were:

```sh
ls -m
```

---

```
bfilec.ext, bfilef.ext, bfilei.ext, bfilel.ext, bfileo.ext, bfiler.ext,
bfileu.ext, bfilex.ext, efilec.ext, efilef.ext, efilei.ext, efilel.ext,
efileo.ext, efiler.ext, efileu.ext, efilex.ext, hfilec.ext, hfilef.ext,
hfilei.ext, hfilel.ext, hfileo.ext, hfiler.ext, hfileu.ext, hfilex.ext,
kfilec.ext, kfilef.ext, kfilei.ext, kfilel.ext, kfileo.ext, kfiler.ext,
kfileu.ext, kfilex.ext, nfilec.ext, nfilef.ext, nfilei.ext, nfilel.ext,
nfileo.ext, nfiler.ext, nfileu.ext, nfilex.ext, qfilec.ext, qfilef.ext,
qfilei.ext, qfilel.ext, qfileo.ext, qfiler.ext, qfileu.ext, qfilex.ext,
tfilec.ext, tfilef.ext, tfilei.ext, tfilel.ext, tfileo.ext, tfiler.ext,
tfileu.ext, tfilex.ext, wfilec.ext, wfilef.ext, wfilei.ext, wfilel.ext,
wfileo.ext, wfiler.ext, wfileu.ext, wfilex.ext, zfilec.ext, zfilef.ext,
zfilei.ext, zfilel.ext, zfileo.ext, zfiler.ext, zfileu.ext, zfilex.ext
```

And then I tested it...

```sh
while ...; do ...; done | { HOME=/dev/null; paste -d', ' - ~ - ~; }
```

---

```
mv ./bfilex.ext ./bfile24.ext, mv ./efilex.ext ./efile24.ext,
mv ./hfilex.ext ./hfile24.ext, mv ./kfilex.ext ./kfile24.ext,
mv ./nfilex.ext ./nfile24.ext, mv ./qfilex.ext ./qfile24.ext,
mv ./tfilex.ext ./tfile24.ext, mv ./wfilex.ext ./wfile24.ext,
mv ./zfilex.ext ./zfile24.ext, mv ./bfileu.ext ./bfile21.ext,
mv ./efileu.ext ./efile21.ext, mv ./hfileu.ext ./hfile21.ext,
mv ./kfileu.ext ./kfile21.ext, mv ./nfileu.ext ./nfile21.ext,
mv ./qfileu.ext ./qfile21.ext, mv ./tfileu.ext ./tfile21.ext,
mv ./wfileu.ext ./wfile21.ext, mv ./zfileu.ext ./zfile21.ext,
mv ./bfiler.ext ./bfile18.ext, mv ./efiler.ext ./efile18.ext,
mv ./hfiler.ext ./hfile18.ext, mv ./kfiler.ext ./kfile18.ext,
mv ./nfiler.ext ./nfile18.ext, mv ./qfiler.ext ./qfile18.ext,
mv ./tfiler.ext ./tfile18.ext, mv ./wfiler.ext ./wfile18.ext,
mv ./zfiler.ext ./zfile18.ext, mv ./bfileo.ext ./bfile15.ext,
mv ./efileo.ext ./efile15.ext, mv ./hfileo.ext ./hfile15.ext,
mv ./kfileo.ext ./kfile15.ext, mv ./nfileo.ext ./nfile15.ext,
mv ./qfileo.ext ./qfile15.ext, mv ./tfileo.ext ./tfile15.ext,
mv ./wfileo.ext ./wfile15.ext, mv ./zfileo.ext ./zfile15.ext,
mv ./bfilel.ext ./bfile12.ext, mv ./efilel.ext ./efile12.ext,
mv ./hfilel.ext ./hfile12.ext, mv ./kfilel.ext ./kfile12.ext,
mv ./nfilel.ext ./nfile12.ext, mv ./qfilel.ext ./qfile12.ext,
mv ./tfilel.ext ./tfile12.ext, mv ./wfilel.ext ./wfile12.ext,
mv ./zfilel.ext ./zfile12.ext, mv ./bfilei.ext ./bfile09.ext,
mv ./efilei.ext ./efile09.ext, mv ./hfilei.ext ./hfile09.ext,
mv ./kfilei.ext ./kfile09.ext, mv ./nfilei.ext ./nfile09.ext,
mv ./qfilei.ext ./qfile09.ext, mv ./tfilei.ext ./tfile09.ext,
mv ./wfilei.ext ./wfile09.ext, mv ./zfilei.ext ./zfile09.ext,
mv ./bfilef.ext ./bfile06.ext, mv ./efilef.ext ./efile06.ext,
mv ./hfilef.ext ./hfile06.ext, mv ./kfilef.ext ./kfile06.ext,
mv ./nfilef.ext ./nfile06.ext, mv ./qfilef.ext ./qfile06.ext,
mv ./tfilef.ext ./tfile06.ext, mv ./wfilef.ext ./wfile06.ext,
mv ./zfilef.ext ./zfile06.ext, mv ./bfilec.ext ./bfile03.ext,
mv ./efilec.ext ./efile03.ext, mv ./hfilec.ext ./hfile03.ext,
mv ./kfilec.ext ./kfile03.ext, mv ./nfilec.ext ./nfile03.ext,
mv ./qfilec.ext ./qfile03.ext, mv ./tfilec.ext ./tfile03.ext,
mv ./wfilec.ext ./wfile03.ext, mv ./zfilec.ext ./zfile03.ext,
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative suggestion, which doesn't support missing files, but I felt the need to try a more "functional" solution that works on tuples:

```
#!/bin/bash
splitfile_renamer() {
  mv splitfile$1 splitfile$2.csv
}

paste <(echo -en {a..z}"\n") <(seq 26) | while read args
  do splitfile_renamer $args
done
```

The above uses `paste` to create the argument tuples (separated by whitespace), and passes them to a pre-made function which then takes them in as numbered arguments.